# Merge down/add a layer on all layers bellow it with GIMP

Tags: gimp, animation, gif

I wanted to add some text on an GIF animation. After downloading few GIF editors and finding them all complete crap, I opened GIF in GIMP.

GIMP displays every step of the animation as a layer:

[image: image description]

I expanded the whole image to contain my text:

[image: image description]

And I created a layer containing some text, which I carefully positioned exactly above the image:

[image: image description]

But the problem is, how can I add that layer easily on all 30 (or even more) steps of the animation?

Answer (score 2):

You need a script, for instance [interleave-layers](http://gimp-tools.sourceforge.net/animationtools.shtml) in "title" mode.

Answer (score 0):

Well, other way its in the layer dialog, You can do this  toggling between the duplicate layer button on the right and the raise up layer arrow button on the left.  But indeed, when its too much its better to do the script.

Good luck!

Comment: You also have to merge the layer...

Comment: thats right, the script seems to be more affordable